# Why does the swap through pointer not work in vector in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have the following code:

```
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void myswap(T* a, T* b)
{
    T temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
}

template<class T>
void printArr(vector<T> arr)
{
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]";
}

void sampleSwap(vector<int> arr)
{
    //swapping first two element
    myswap(&arr[0], &arr[1]);
    printArr(arr);
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand(500);

    vector<int> arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr.push_back(rand() % LIMIT);
    }

    printArr(arr);
    cout << endl;

    sampleSwap(arr);
    printArr(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
[ 398 57 417 270 271 918 903 314 569 70 ]
[ 57 398 417 270 271 918 903 314 569 70 ]
[ 398 57 417 270 271 918 903 314 569 70 ]
```

I tried to swap the first and second elements of my vector. The vector content is changed in the function but it doesn't retain the change after the function exits. Am I missing something?

Comment: You take a *copy* of you vector in sampleSwap, use pass by reference: `sampleSwap(vector<int>& arr)`

Comment: Read about *pass by value* versus *pass by reference*.

Comment: Oh! Pretty silly. Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass the `vector` by value to `sampleSwap`, so only a copy of the `vector` you have in the `main` gets modified. Pass by reference instead:

```
void sampleSwap(vector<int> &arr)
                            ^
```